# For what values of k does an eigenbasis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ exists with respect to matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck with the following problem.

For what values of k does an eigenbasis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ exists with respect to matrix A, when

A = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & k\\ 1 & 1 & k\\ 1 & 1 & k
\end{bmatrix}$

I thought that the value of k might be one, since then the matrix is symmetric. Since it's symmetric, all the algebraic and geometric multiplicities are equal, thus for k = 1 A has an eigenbasis. Is this correct? And how can I find out for other values of k?

Comment: As to your first point: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523375/is-it-true-that-all-symmetric-matrices-have-eigenbasis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k \neq 1$, then

$$A \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x + y + kz \\ x + y + kz \\ x + y + kz \end{pmatrix}.$$

In order for this to be an eigenvector, i.e.

$$ \lambda \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x + y + kz \\ x + y + kz \\ x + y + kz \end{pmatrix},$$

we need to have either $x = y = z$, or $\lambda = 0$. The first equation gives one of the eigenvectors (with eigenvalue $2 + k$), i.e. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

If $\lambda = 0$, then solve $x + y + kz = 0$. There are always two linearly independent solutions, but what should you watch out for?

Answer (score 0):

You are right for $k=1$ we can find an eigenbasis.

More in general the eigenvectors are

- $v_1=(1,-1,0)$
- $v_2=(k,0,-1)$
- $v_3=(1,1,1)$

then we need to assure that they are lineary independent, that is

$$\det\begin{pmatrix} 1&k&1 \\ -1 &0&1\\ 0&-1&1 \end{pmatrix}=2+k\neq 0$$

Comment: @piet You are welcome! Bye